# jQuery Target Collection of IDs with multiple requirements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-table

I'd like to be able to target a collection of elements, but with multiple requirements.  For example:

```
<tr id="tr_brown_tall_young"><td></td></tr>
<tr id="tr_blue_tall_adult"><td></td></tr>
<tr id="tr_blue_short_adult"><td></td></tr>
<tr id="tr_green_short_old"><td></td></tr>

// Say I want to show rows only of people with blue eyes and tall height
$('[id*=tr_]).hide();
$('[id*=blue] && [id*=tall]').show(); // This is what I can't figure out how to do
```

Unfortunately I can't apply one filter and then the other, because of potential overlaps.  In the example above, people who have blue eyes OR are tall would show up.  Is there a way to do this in jQuery?  If not, perhaps a different JS library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its just the wrong separator - Here you go,

**This is when you want the OR condition:**

```
$('[id*=tall_], [id~=blue_]').hide();
```

You can find a more complete example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/sagive/o7cef4jy/13/

.

**This is when you want the AND condition:**

```
$('[id*=tall_][id*=blue_]').hide();
```

Comment: This does "OR" not "AND" - your third option "tall and blue" also hides "tall and brown" which is not "tall" *and* "blue"

Comment: It's the difference between  "blue rows and tall rows" and "rows that are blue and tall"